# What does multimap find() return in existence of multple objects with same Key?

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, std

Is multimap find(key) guaranteed to return an iterator to the FIRST element with key "key" ?
I couldn't find a proper answer in documentation anywhere.

Comment: Can you please elaborate, what specifically told [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/find) is unclear for you? [Edit] your question,  and be specific in reference to the linked documentation.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for [lower_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/lower_bound)?

Comment: Acording to this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/find it not not defined that it will return any specific element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::multimap::find(key)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/find) returns an iterator on *any* element whose key compares equal to `key`:

> Finds an element with key equivalent to key. If there are several elements with key in the container, any of them may be returned.